# array filter not working on MongoDB objectId arays

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, filter

I need an array of IDs not in a different array of IDs.
I have no problem with straight javascript - but when I try to use arrays returned from MongoDB - the filters do not work.

Examples:

First let's see the two arrays...

```
x.user_ids is ["5b579074dc1eac0014276442","5b574e03dc1eac0014276418"] 
x.user_bad_ids is ["5b574e03dc1eac0014276419","5b579074dc1eac0014276442"]
```

I would like the final array to be (in this example there is only one "good" id)

```
["5b574e03dc1eac0014276418"]
```

I have tried a SIMPLE filter

```
console.log( x.user_ids.filter(e => !x.user_bad_ids.includes(e)) );
```

but I get

```
[ 5b579074dc1eac0014276442, 5b574e03dc1eac0014276418 ]
```

I note there are now quotes...I am not sure if js does not like objectid arrays from mongo

I tried something more 'old school'

```
var tempArr = x.user_ids.filter(function(item) {
    return !x.user_bad_ids.includes(item);
});
console.log( tempArr );
```

but I get

```
[ 5b579074dc1eac0014276442, 5b574e03dc1eac0014276418 ]
```

And lastly - some verbose function

```
    Array.prototype.uniqueFrom = function() {
      if (!arguments.length)
        return [];
      var a1 = this.slice(0); // Start with a copy

      for (var n=0; n < arguments.length; n++) {
        var a2 = arguments[n];
        if (!(a2 instanceof Array))
          throw new TypeError( 'argument ['+n+'] must be Array' );

        for(var i=0; i<a2.length; i++) {
          var index = a1.indexOf(a2[i]);
          if (index > -1) {
            a1.splice(index, 1);
          }
        }
      }
      return a1;
    }

    console.log( x.user_ids.uniqueFrom(x.user_bad_ids) );
```

I get

```
[ 5b579074dc1eac0014276442, 5b574e03dc1eac0014276418 ]
```

In all cases I expect ...76442 to be filtered out, am I missing something about arrays of object ids coming out of mongo?

Comment: Did you check the type of `ObjectId` returned from MongoDB? I suspect it could be an object representation - in that case you may need to convert that to a `string` while comparing

Comment: thx Ajai - example?

Comment: `x.user_ids.filter(id => !x.user_bad_ids.some(badId => id.toString() === badId.toString()))` ref: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.toString/